# Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug) MAMP OS X

Tags: php, macos, netbeans, mamp, xdebug

**Preamble**

After many hours, I have been unable to get NetBeans to connect to xdebug. Some months ago, after upgrading from an old version of MAMP to MAMP PRO, debugging worked flawlessly. A week ago it started getting flakey. It would appear to connect but would not stop at the breakpoints. Restarting NetBeans (v7.0.1) and apache sometimes got it working for a short time.

I really needed it fixed so I installed the latest version of MAMP PRO (2.1.2). Now I get the Waiting For Connection message forever.

**Testing I have done**

While the Waiting For Connection message is there with the moving bar, I look to see if it’s listening. It is...

```
# lsof -i -n -P |grep 9001
java  6496  tim  230u  IPv6 0xffffff80239d8190      0t0    TCP *:9001 (LISTEN)
```

In NetBeans php config I have the interpreter set to:
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php

Executing the following:

```
# /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php -i | grep xdebug
```

tells me that xdebug is running as does phpinfo()

I have (many times) confirmed that I have the port number the same everywhere. I have tried port 9000 and 9001.

Doing a tail on *xdebug.log* then initiating a session from the browser without starting a debug session in NetBeans produces:

```
I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9001.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
```

With the waiting for connection message *and* initiating a session from the browser, I get this in the log:

```
: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9001.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///Users/tim/MAMPSites/facts.tvd.us/htdocs/sendfile/tim.php" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="7279" idekey="netbeans-xdebug"><engine version="2.2.1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>
```

My php.ini file has the following:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.20/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

**Update**

I just noticed that the lsof command above shows NetBeans listening on ipV6. Forcing java (NetBeans) to use ipV4 does not help.

```
launchctl setenv JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

I found a post that suggested a test to confirm xdebug is working correctly. Create a php file:

```
<?php
$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 9000;
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die('Unable to bind');
socket_listen($sock);
$client = socket_accept($sock);
echo "connection established: $client";
socket_close($client);
socket_close($sock);
?>
```

Run it from the command line and load any page in your browser with the following at the end of the url:

```
?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=nb
```

If it outputs something like "connection established: Resource id #5", xdebug is working correctly. With that, I reinstalled Java and NetBeans. I told NetBeans NOT to import my existing preferences... Still no connection.

**Update2**

I installed the phpStorm IDE for Mac. I learned enough about it to get the debugger running with my existing MAMP and xdebug setup. I think this confirms the problem is with NetBeans.

At this point, getting this working seems impossible. :(

Comment: My final resolution to this problem... I've completely switched to phpStorm. After using it for a few days, it seems to be a much better IDE (in my opinion). Debugging just "works."

Comment: Exactly the same here ! I tried to install xdebug with netbeans for 2 weeks, then i gave up and switched to PHPStorm (on Windows7 btw). Works perfectly out of the box. Sometimes it's worth paying for good software.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I asked the same thing and got this quite good answer: [How to track execution time of each line / block of lines / methods in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17651854/1114320), beside that i have this answer also on a currently running other question with the same content.

Some additional notes on that (stuff i've collected in other SO posts in my own research with this problem):

1. The port might be also 9001 (seems to work for some people while 9000 don't).
2. Switching to PHPStorm IDE is a real alternative that solves this problem (as PHPStorm has included perfectly running xdebug already).
3. Download a new version of xdebug via the wizard (http://xdebug.org/wizard.php) and if you follow the instructions maybe you will be lucky.
4. Switching off the firewall might help.
5. Add to php.ini: `xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug`.
6. Find out if you have a xdebug.ini file and add the xdebug related php.ini lines to that file.
7. you have to un-comment the zend_extension line (i.e. remove the `;` at its begninning), so Xdebug is actually loaded.
8. make sure Xdebug is loaded, calling phpinfo() from a PHP file (just to be sure).

Comment: Thanks. Adding `xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug` to php.ini did the magic for me.

Comment: Adding xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug also fixed my issue with NetBeans. And I also installed the PHPStorm but unfortunately it didn't have XDebug pre-installed and it needed many extra steps, and still it couldn't do the debug. Though it is awesome IDE but for almost $150/year I expected it to work right out of the box or with minimal setup, which wasn't the case. I'll stay with NetBeans for now.

Answer (score 5):

Xdebug will only connect if there is an index.php file in your project folder, so check to make sure you have one.

Answer (score 1):

it works for me now. I have LAMP installed. I modified according to all answers from above, started apache2 and now it flies... i am happy... for some time i thought to switch to phpstorm, but I reconsidered... tweak a little more... et voila. it's working.

Here what I have in php.ini

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so

xdebug.max_nesting_level = 250
xdebug.auto_trace=On
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.trace_output_dir=/var/www/AMRO
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

Answer (score 0):

On clean download and install of netbeans working on xampp, xdebug worked except would not stop at breakpoints.  Changed php.ini to: xdebug.remote_enable = 1 (from 0) and xdebug worked as expected!